# How to make android zoom control auto disappear like the built in zoom controls do

Tags: android, controller, zooming

I had to change the position of the zoomcontrols. For this purpose, I used android zoom controls and implemented zoom in and zoom out functions in its listener. However, now i was thinking them to behave in the same manner the built in zoom controls do i.e. they auto disappear. How to do it as i don't want the android zoom control to stay forever on the screen.

Thanks 
Astha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply an `AlphaAnimation` to the widget, going from an alpha of 1.0 (opaque) to 0.0 (transparent). Start the animation whenever you want it to fade out. Set up an `AnimationListener` on the `AlphaAnimation` to call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the widget when the animation ends. When you want the widget to re-appear, call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.